# ReflectionException class yii\twig\ViewRenderer does not exists

Tags: yii2, twig-extension

I'm using Twig in Yii2 (basic template) but I got that error "ReflectionException  Class yii\twig\ViewRenderer does not exist in Yii2". Where I can fix it?

This is my config:

## 1. In web.php:

```
'view'=>[
'class'=>'yii\web\View',
'renderers'=>[
'twig'=>[
'class'=>'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
'cachePath'=>'@runtime/Twig/cache',
'options' => YII_DEBUG ? [
'debug' => true,
'auto_reload' => true,] : [],
'extensions' => YII_DEBUG ?
['\Twig_Extension_Debug', : [],
'globals' => [
'html' => '\yii\helpers\Html',
'yii' => 'Yii'],
```

## 2. In composer.json

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.4.0",
"yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
"yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
"yiisoft/yii2-twig": "*"
},
```

Comment: you just refer this link to solve your problem....https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig

Comment: I downloaded and added folder yii2-twig in to yiisoft, config like above but still not work. Did you have any example code?

Comment: refer this link....https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

Comment: you add `"yiisoft/yii2-twig": "~2.0.0"` instead of `"yiisoft/yii2-twig": "*"` in composer.json file. Than update composer using `composer update` command.

Comment: I don't know what something wrong but I still not fix that error. Could you please give me a example code?